# Terminal commands for accessing clipboard

Tags: terminal, copy-paste

I am trying to access the clipboard from the terminal, but there is no `pbcopy` or `pbpaste` command.

I want to use a command, because if I can access the clipboard with a command, then I can more easily integrate clipboard access into the program that I am writing. It is for a C program and a Python program. For C, I use  `system("pbpaste")` and for Python, I use `os.system("pbpaste")`.

Is there an alternative to this command? How can I access the clipboard from the terminal?

Comment: If you advise which terminal this is for. Termux has a command line access to clipboard via termux-api